# Mongod Error: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod instance already running?

Tags: mongodb, terminal

---

> 2017-06-12T13:06:18.407+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>   **exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating**
>   2017-06-12T13:06:18.407+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten]
>    **shutdown: going to close listening sockets...**
>   2017-06-12T13:06:18.407+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten]
>    **shutdown: going to flush diaglog...**
>   2017-06-12T13:06:18.407+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>    **now exiting**
>   2017-06-12T13:06:18.407+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>   **shutting down with code:100**

Comment: Not really enough information here. But also. This really should be asked on [dba,stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is for questions and answers relating to database administration and configuration. StackOverflow is for :"programming" based questions, of which this is not. Please move your post to the appropriate site instead of posting here. But please add some more information when posting there.

Comment: Can you check if an instance of mongod is already running? On *nix systems, you can run `ps -eaf | grep mongod` to find out the process id of running mongod. Also, check whether the `/data/db` directory is already created. If created, check the permissions whether you can write/read data.

Comment: go to /data/db/ folder delete mongod.lock file it will solve your problem. this problem occurs becoz you did't shut down mongodb properly

Comment: thank you @NeilLunn I will try that

Comment: yes I have the /data/db directory but how can I check the permissions? sorry I am totally new for that @harshavmb

Comment: Paste the output of `ps -eaf  | grep mongod` and `ls -lart` commands

Comment: I got this:   drwxr-xr-x   3 root      wheel  102 Oct 15  2016 .  
drwx------   3 _postfix  wheel  102 Jun 10 03:34 postfix  
drwxr-xr-x  25 root      wheel  850 Jun 10 03:49 ..    @harshavmb

Comment: @MohitJain I will try it and let you know, thanks

Comment: Your output isn't clear to me. Can you format ? Also, where are you running this command? You should run on `/data/db` directory. Run `ls -lart /data/db/`

Comment: @harshavmb sorry for that, after running this "ls -lart /data/db/" I got this:
 total 496  
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     49 Jun 10 17:17 WiredTiger  
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     21 Jun 10 17:17 WiredTiger.lock  
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     95 Jun 10 17:17 storage.bson  
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel      5 Jun 10 18:31 mongod.lock

Comment: Can you run `cat /data/db/mongod.lock` command and paste the output? Also, can you let me know how you are running `mongod` process? I'm also expecting `ps -eaf | grep mongod` output

Comment: @harshavmb I can't paste everything because of the characters limit, but the problem is what I got from running the commands you till me is something like this:  "-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 49 Jun 10 17:17 WiredTiger" , and many similar lines of that

Comment: @harshavmb I use "sudo mongod", I got this "cat: mongod.lock: No such file or directory"

Comment: Again, you are running in a wrong directory. Run `cat /data/db/mongod.lock` and what about the other command output. I need to see the output of that command as well.

Comment: from running this command `ps -eaf | grep mongod`  I got   `0  9321     1   0 Sat06PM ??         0:00.04 sudo mongod
    0  9322  9321   0 Sat06PM ??         2:40.14 mongod
  501 11986 11695   0  1:58PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep mongod` @harshavmb

Comment: Can you format?

Comment: yes sure @harshavmb

Comment: Run `sudo kill 9321` to kill the running process, delete the mongod.lock file using `sudo rm /data/db/mongod.lock` file and then start `sudo mongod`

Comment: wow you are amazing thank you so much it is working @harshavmb I thought I had to re-install mongo, Thanks ^_^

Comment: Glad to see the issue is fixed!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error clearly says

> exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file:
>   /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod
>   instance already running?, terminating

An instance of mongod is already running and it held a lock on `mongod.lock` file. Run `ps -eaf | grep mongod` to find the running instance. If running, kill the process `sudo kill <pID>` obtained from above grep command.

Then delete the `mongod.lock` file as mongod wasn't shutdown gracefully. Post deleting the lock file start the mongod process `sudo mongod`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please accept it. Thanks

Comment: That's good but what to do when you have Docker Swarm and automatically increase/decrease # of replicas?