# CrashLoopBackOff while increasing replicas count more than 1 on Azure AKS cluster for MongoDB image

Tags: mongodb, azure, ubuntu, kubernetes

[Click here to get error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgtfV.png)

I am deploying MongoDb to Azure AKS with Azure File Share as Volume (using persistent volume & persistent volume claim). If I am increasing replicas more than one then CrashLoopBackOff is occurring. Only one Pod is getting created, other are getting failed.

**My Docker file to Create MongoDb image.**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927

RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_CODENAME | cut -d= -f2)/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org

EXPOSE 27017

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
```

**YAML file for Deployment**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:      
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: <my image of mongodb>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          protocol: TCP
          name: mongo 
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/db
          name: az-files-mongo-storage
      volumes:
      - name: az-files-mongo-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mong-pvc
      ---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongo
```

Comment: I think it's a problem with share volume between pods.

Comment: But, as per azure documentation I am using  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany , which means that the File share can be accessed from multiple pod.

Comment: From the error, it seems the mongo cannot initialize in the same volume for many times. Maybe you can just store data in it. Do not initialize in the volume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your issue, you can take a look at another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497009/mongod-error-98-unable-to-lock-file-data-db-mongod-lock-resource-temporarily/44498179) for the same error. So it seems you cannot initialize the same volume when another has already done it for mongo. From the error, I will suggest you just use the volume to store the data. You can initialize in the Dockerfile when creating the image. Or you can use the create volumes for every pod through the [StatefulSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-clusters-workloads#statefulsets) and it's more recommended.

**Update:**

The yam file below will work for you:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo 
  serviceName: mongo
  replicas: 3 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo 
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: charlesacr.azurecr.io/mongodb:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          name: mongo
        volumeMounts:
        - name: az-files-mongo-storage
          mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: az-files-mongo-storage
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: az-files-mongo-storage
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
```

And you need to create the StorageClass before you create the statefulSets. The yam file below:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: az-files-mongo-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

Then the pods work well and the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your continuous help. Based on your guidance I followed the below steps. 1. On my host local Linux Machine, I did az login. 2. az aks get-credentials --resource-group <nane-of-RG> --name <cluster-name> 3. Created a storage class using your yaml file. 4. Created the service using your yaml file. 5. Created a StatefulSet using your yaml file. 6. kubectl get pods. But it is showing no resource found and I checked my Azure account, no storage account is creating automatically.  Did I miss any other step ?

Comment: As I see, you are using image as : charlesacr.azurecr.io/mongodb:v1 . Dose this image differ from my image (roushang7cr/mongo:v1.0) ? As I already specified , I have created the image using the above specified Dockerfile. Dose there any impact of this image ?

Comment: @Roushan I use your Dockerfile to create the image, just store it in the ACR. This is not a problem.

Comment: @Roushan And the storage class is a dynamic volume, they are created in the AKS group named MC_xxx_xxx_xxx.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick response. I appreciate your help. Before, manually I created an storage account named mongo-sa inside my Resource Group named MC_AKS_RG_cluster01_southeastasia. So, I deleted that storage account , and re-applied the yaml file. Now I am getting a new storage account created inside MC_AKS_RG_cluster01_southeastasia . But till now no pod is getting created. kubectl get pod is showing "no resource found".  kubectl get statefulset is giving me the result. kubectl get pvc is giving me one record with BOUND status. kubectl get pv giving me one record.

Comment: @Roushan How do you create the statefulset? Can you show the command that you execute? And can you provide the event details?

Comment: I have created a single yaml file which contains 1.Storageclass 2. Service 3. Statefulset sequentially. then I executed the command "kubectl apply -f <my-yaml-file-name>.yaml. I executed "kubectl get events", it is showing provisioning  PersistentVolumeClaim is succedded. And -->   create Pod mongo-0 in StatefulSet mongo failed error: Pod "mongo-0" is invalid: spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "azurefile-mongo".

Comment: @Roushan It's a mistake in the statefulset yaml file. I have updated the answer. volumeMounts.name must the same with the volumeClaimTemplates.metadata.name.

Comment: @Roushan If it works for you, please mark it. If not, please let me know what's the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. It is working now perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `accessModes: - ReadWriteMany`. But still, the volume or storage type should support this mode. [Find the table here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

According to that table, AzureFile supports ReadWriteMany but not AzureDisk.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using StatefulSets for mongodb. deployments are for stateless services.